# How do I insert "COALESCE"?

Tags: postgresql

This is my Error msg:
"ERROR:  COALESCE types text and integer cannot be matched
LINE 431: and hrot_hrpaycd_id = 6)),0) as ROT,"

How do I insert "COALESCE"?

```
coalesce(
  select formatQty(round(sum(hrprocinc_amount),2)) 
  from hrprocinc 
  where         
    hrprocinc_hrprocemp_id=v_payslip.hrprocemp_id
    and hrprocinc_hrot_id in (
      select hrot_id from hrot, hrpaycd, hrprocinc, hrprocemp, hremp
      where hrprocinc_hrot_id = hrot_id 
        and hrprocinc_hrpaycd_id = hrpaycd_id
        and hrpaycd_id = hrot_hrpaycd_id 
        and hrprocinc_hrprocemp_id = hrprocemp_id
        and hrprocemp_hremp_id = hremp_id
        and hrot_nd = FALSE
        and hrot_hrpaycd_id = 6
    ),
  0) as ROT
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect formatQty() returns a string, and you're trying to coalesce that with an integer. I suppose a quick and possibly *very* dirty check would be to quote the integer.

But I'd be inclined to remove formatQty(), myself. Leave the formatting to application code, if that's possible.